# Handling mouse events in javafx

Tags: javafx, mouseevent

Can i set a function when creating an object like i can with variables?

Given i have a container class and a CustomButton class:

```
function doSomething():Void{}

var button:CustomButton = CustomButton{
   posX : 50;
   posY = 100;
   onMouseClicked: doSomething;

}
```

Short story: i need the main container object to handle mouse events that occurs in objects placed in the containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest change for you is to change:

```
function doSomething():Void{}
```

to

```
function doSomething(e:MouseEvent):Void{}
```

The action property is nice but I'm sure you want some custom rollover effect or something using onMouseEntered etc.

Comment: A combination of these things worked out. I did try out sending the MouseEvent as a parameter, but that didn't work and i couldn't find any documentation on the syntax of passing functions. 

  var towerButton: GenericButton = GenericButton{
                   onMouseClicked: doSomething
               }
This will correctly call doSomething(e:MouseEvent).

Comment: Oh you want to pass a function to another? 

function doSomething(function(MouseEvent):otherfunc):Void { ... }

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your requirement correctly, I think it can be achieved with some syntax changes.  Obviously you can extend Button if you need a custom version:

```
function doSomething():Void{
    println("clicked");
}

var button:Button = Button{
    text: "Click Me"
    translateX: 50;
    translateY: 100;
    action: doSomething
}
Stage {
    title : "ButtonTest"
    scene: Scene {
        width: 200
        height: 200
        content: [ button ]
    }
}
```